# Is the 180x180 icon literally required?

Tags: ios, icons, app-store, iphone-6-plus

Regarding the app icon,

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

Note that it asserts a 180x180 icon is now **"required"**.

Interestingly, if you don't bother putting in a 180x180 icon, in fact it still builds and runs fine to the simulator or to devices.

of course, obviously all sensible studios will include 180.180 icons for their clients.

I'm curious, in fact **will Apple reject it** if there's no 180x180 icon?

Will it be rejected automatically at the validation step?

Has anyone actually tried and found this out?

Obviously it's generally easy for clients or your art department to create a 170x170 icon -

I'm curious how literally it is "required". For example, with 100,000s apps, will some studios / small operators not bother?

For example, will we see scaled-up icons?

Comment: Remember how bad the regular icons looked when the iPhone 4 retina came out? Current retina icons look almost as bad on the new iPhone 6 Plus if there are not 180x180.

Comment: Hi Desdenova, I don't know how clear I can be -- I am curious IF they will actually reject.

Comment: Hi, it's hard to say without a proof. But I think it won't even pass the Xcode validation.

Comment: Hi @Desdenova.  Yes that's exactly what I'm asking - as it says in the question!

Answer (score 2):

If you support the iPhone 6+ (i.e., you have a launch XIB/Storyboard), my guess is that they'll reject it.

Honestly, this just seems like one of those things that are not worth fighting. Why would you want to degrade the experience of the most enthusiastic users with the most expensive device?

Comment: A good point on the launch-duality.  I'm wondering what will actually happen.  (As Desdenova points out - will it be rejected at the validation step?)

Comment: Hey Stephen - as I explained in the question, it's an interesting workflow issue.  Eg, for clients w/ 100s of apps is it worth bothering / necessary ... is it just scaled down from a big one anyway (which would be perfect anyway) ... etc.  Not a biggie, just a curiosity.  Cheers